# Missing data after step_naomit in fit_resamples

Tags: r, tidymodels, r-recipes, r-ranger

I am currently applying the following recipe and workflow in order to fit a Random Forest using 5 folds cross validation using `fit_resamples`. The workflow looks something like this:

```r
library(tidymodels)

# import data and convert response to factor
train <- read.csv('https://pastebin.com/raw/LJQqdEEE')
train$accepted <- as.factor(train$accepted)

# Train/test split
new_split <- initial_split(train, prop = 0.7)
new_train <- training(new_split)
new_test <- testing(new_split)

# Feature engineering and data prep
admission_rec <- 
  recipe(accepted ~ ., data = new_train) %>% 
  step_impute_median(sat) %>% 
  step_mutate(
    ap_scores = strsplit(as.character(ap_scores), ';'),
    ap_score_max = max(as.numeric(unlist(ap_scores))),
    ap_score_avg = mean(as.numeric(unlist(ap_scores))),
    ap_score_min = min(as.numeric(unlist(ap_scores))),
    ap_score_med = median(as.numeric(unlist(ap_scores)))
  ) %>% 
  step_dummy(ethnicity, one_hot = T) %>% 
  step_center(c(essay_strength, family_income, sat), skip = T) %>%
  step_scale(c(essay_strength, family_income, sat), skip = T) %>%
  step_naomit(everything(), skip = T) %>% 
  step_rm(ap_scores)

# Random forest model and workflow
rf_spec <- 
  rand_forest() %>% 
  set_engine('ranger') %>% 
  set_mode('classification')

rf_workflow <- 
  workflow() %>% 
  add_recipe(admission_rec) %>% 
  add_model(rf_spec)

# Cross validation
cv_folds <- 
  vfold_cv(new_train, v = 5)

# Fit model
rf_res <- rf_workflow %>%
  fit_resamples(
    resamples = cv_folds,
    metrics = metric_set(
      recall, precision, f_meas, accuracy,
      kap, roc_auc, sens, spec
    )
  )
```

When fitting the model I am prompted with the following failure message:

```
preprocessor 1/1: There are new levels in a factor: NA
preprocessor 1/1, model 1/1 (predictions): Missing data in columns: ethnicity_Asian ...
```

This looks limited to the one hot encoded columns and even with `step_naomit(skip = TRUE)`. For this reason, I've erroneously thought that placing `step_naomit` after `step_mutate` would take care of it.

I am probably overlooking something fairly simple here, this is my first stab at `{tidymodels}` after a long R hyathus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track. `step_naomit()` is unfortunately not the answer, the error arises in `step_dummy()` because it contains missing data and it doesn't know how to deal with it. The solution is to use `step_unknown()` right before, it will take a factor variable and assign "unknown" to missing values.

I would also recommend that you do not set `skip = T` in `step_center()` and `step_scale()` as it would apply centering and scaling when fitting the model but would skip if when the model is used later on, such as in prediction. This would strange and undesired results.

```r
library(tidymodels)
train <- read.csv('https://pastebin.com/raw/LJQqdEEE')
train$accepted <- as.factor(train$accepted)

# Train/test split
new_split <- initial_split(train, prop = 0.7)
new_train <- training(new_split)
new_test <- testing(new_split)

# Feature engineering and data prep
admission_rec <- 
  recipe(accepted ~ ., data = new_train) %>% 
  step_impute_median(sat) %>% 
  step_mutate(
    ap_scores = strsplit(as.character(ap_scores), ';'),
    ap_score_max = max(as.numeric(unlist(ap_scores))),
    ap_score_avg = mean(as.numeric(unlist(ap_scores))),
    ap_score_min = min(as.numeric(unlist(ap_scores))),
    ap_score_med = median(as.numeric(unlist(ap_scores)))
  ) %>%
  step_unknown(ethnicity) %>%
  step_dummy(ethnicity, one_hot = T) %>%
  step_center(c(essay_strength, family_income, sat)) %>%
  step_scale(c(essay_strength, family_income, sat)) %>%
  step_rm(ap_scores)

# Random forest model and workflow
rf_spec <- 
  rand_forest() %>% 
  set_engine('ranger') %>% 
  set_mode('classification')

rf_workflow <- 
  workflow() %>% 
  add_recipe(admission_rec) %>% 
  add_model(rf_spec)

# Cross validation
cv_folds <- 
  vfold_cv(new_train, v = 5)

# Fit model
rf_res <- rf_workflow %>%
  fit_resamples(
    resamples = cv_folds,
    metrics = metric_set(
      recall, precision, f_meas, accuracy,
      kap, roc_auc, sens, spec
    )
  )

rf_res
#> # Resampling results
#> # 5-fold cross-validation 
#> # A tibble: 5 x 4
#>   splits            id    .metrics         .notes          
#>   <list>            <chr> <list>           <list>          
#> 1 <split [560/140]> Fold1 <tibble [8 × 4]> <tibble [0 × 1]>
#> 2 <split [560/140]> Fold2 <tibble [8 × 4]> <tibble [0 × 1]>
#> 3 <split [560/140]> Fold3 <tibble [8 × 4]> <tibble [0 × 1]>
#> 4 <split [560/140]> Fold4 <tibble [8 × 4]> <tibble [0 × 1]>
#> 5 <split [560/140]> Fold5 <tibble [8 × 4]> <tibble [0 × 1]>
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>